# How can I get all image names in asset catalog group?

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I had a folder of images from which I was getting the names to use as keys to a Dictionary. I have now moved all images to an asset catalog and created groups for the relevant folders. The code using `FileManager` is not working anymore as it can not find any folders (due to the assets being compiled into a `.car` file).

How should I approach this?

Comment: As per my question that you commented on. You can't.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes this is true.. But check my own answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So (following matt's suggestion) here is what I did:

I created a RunScript build phase to run before compiling

[image]

and used a script to create a `txt` file with the names of the files that I can then use during runtime

```
#!/bin/sh
>./your_app_folder/fileNames.txt
for FILE in ./your_app_folder/Images.xcassets/actions/*; do
echo $FILE >> ./your_app_folder/fileNames.txt
done
```

Comment: In 48 hours you can accept your own answer instead of mine. You should do that. I will not be at all offended! Not that that matters, but my point is, this is really a nice solution and posterity deserves to see it as the solution, which the checkmark will show. You did the work here, not me.

Comment: Ah. Excellent answer indeed. It wouldn't work in my particular case as the order of the images is not the same as the alphabetical order. I do like this answer though.

Answer (score 8):

You have two choices:

- Don't Do That. Go right on using a folder of images.
- Supply the keys in some other way. If you don't want to hard-code them into the code itself, you could make a text file. But of course you will have to keep that text file updated as you add / remove images.

You'll notice that I didn't say you could magically introspect the asset catalog. That's because you can't.

Comment: You can, there's some preliminary info [here](https://github.com/davepeck/iOS-artwork)  But you absolutely should NOT even think about it.  The right way is almost certainly to go back to your filesystem approach.

Comment: @David Good info! You and I are using different meanings of the word "can" :)))

Comment: @David thanks guys :) I actually went for the second option but created a run script build phase with a bash script to create the text file programmatically. This is possible since before compilation the xcassets folder is accessible as normal.

Comment: @Dionysis Oooh, cool. I think you should post your bash script as an answer and accept _that_ answer instead of mine. This would be really useful for other people to see!

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that later and was going to recommend it.  The format of the `contents.json` file is pretty trivial to parse, particularly if you already have a json parser.  For that reason I probably would've done it as a python script, but either way :)