# Displaying images in collection view from Images.xcassets folder in ios Swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a Folder of Images in Images.xcassets. I want to display all the images from only that particular folder and load those images in a collection view. I know i will have to write this code to display the images

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Apple")
```

I will have to run a for loop to display all the images in the collection view. But i do not know how to access all the images from the Images.xcassets folder

Comment: One way is to add the names of all images to an array and use it , otherwise create a script like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27930578/4518753

Comment: @good4pc Is there a way to give the path of the folder and create an array of its contents, then access it using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to my understandings, a folder inside the `Assets.xcassets` folder means nothing. If there is a folder called `Jack`, `Apple` then inside `Jack` you have `Apple`. Then you try running `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Apple")`, yes this will work. You don't need `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Jack/Apple")`.

So if you just name your images something like `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, `image4`, `image5` then you can do something like.

```
for index in 0 ..< 5 {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "image%i", index))
}
```

It doesn't matter where the images are located in the files.