# Get number of images in xcasset

Tags: swift, image, loops, xcasset

I want to programmatically load a couple of images into arrays from my xcassets. I don't know how many images there are in the asset, but the images are named in order, like this: `"img1_1"`, `"img1_2"`, `"img2_1"`, `"img2_2"`, ...

I put the images in folders inside the asset, so folder `"images1"` contains all images with names starting with `"img1_"` and the folder called `"images2"` contains all images starting with `"img2_"`. Does that help?

How do I get the number of images in the asset that are named like that so I can iterate through them and add them to my array?

Comment: Did you solve that issue?

Comment: I don't really recall but I believe I used a somewhat modified form of Derek's code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a real easy way to go about it since the files are placed in the app at compile time.  You can, though, create a RunScript in the Build Phases to be ran before compiling that creates a text file of the images.  Then you can read in that text file and populate an array of images.  You can use that array to get the details you need.

*RunScript in the Build Phases*:

```
#!/bin/sh
>./your_app_folder/fileNames.txt
for FILE in ./your_app_folder/Images.xcassets/actions/*; do
echo $FILE >> ./your_app_folder/fileNames.txt
done
```

Also, here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930578/4048853) to an accepted answer that a previous poster asked with more details.

Another option if you do not want to deal with Build Phases, and one I'd probably choose, is not to use the Assets.xcassets file. Just place the images in a folder within your app bundle.  It's much easier to read from the bundle.

**UPDATE:**

For the second option, you can drag your images (or folder of images) to your project, but be sure copy as a folder reference rather than group.  Then in your code, you can read that folder using the FileManager.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let imagePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/your_new_folder"
let imageNames = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imagePath)
```

imageNames in this case will be an array of file names within that url path.  If go this route, you probably have to load the images by contentsOfFile too.

```
if let imagePath = bundle.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil) {
    myImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I go about the second option?

Comment: I updated the answer with more details on the second option.  Just a heads up, the code is in Swift 3.