# Access root file created by script Swift

Tags: swift

From this question: [How can I get all image names in asset catalog group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903681/how-can-i-get-all-image-names-in-asset-catalog-group/27930578#27930578)

I want to access a file created in the root of an App in Swift.

My App is called Challenge and my script is

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
#!/bin/sh
>./Challenge/fileNames.txt
for FILE in ./Challenge/Images.xcassets/actions/*; do
echo $FILE >> ./Challenge/fileNames.txt
done
```

I have tried

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "fileNames.txt"
    let imageNames = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: imagePath)
```

And many other combinations .

This is not homework, I have tried various solutions but as I am not sure where the file is within the file system (how the root can be accessed within the App) I seem unable to locate the file.

Question: How to read ./Challenge/fileNames.txt from an App called challenger, created by a script during the build phase.

Answer (score 0):

The file is located in the main bundle folder, not resource path:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "txt")
let content = try! String(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
```

Comment: Returns nil? I can't believe that the script is wrong from the SO post...

Comment: Hmm. Frustratingly even with the edit I'm getting nil for the path

Comment: `contentsOfDirectory` applied to a **file** path makes no sense.

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns does the file in your project's Copy Bundle Resource section?

Comment: But what's the difference using path instead of resourcePath? Should that really matter using just path?

Comment: I don't know if it does the file other than it does in ./Challenge/fileNames.txt

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns could you look inside your app's package, see if the file did get added? you can find the package in your DerivedData folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Doesn't look like it's there - so the script doesn't work?

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns  yeah, i think it only copy file to your project folder, but Xcode only copy files in Copy Bundle Resource to your app.

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns or maybe it 's problem with the build setting order. does Run Script before or after Copy Bundle Resource?